# How to adding JSON data using Cache library

Tags: swift

I'm using Cache library of "hyperoslo".(https://github.com/hyperoslo/Cache#handling-json-response)

And I try to update swift 3.x to 4.2.
But I got two errors about adding Json data to cache.

One of error message about `Cannot convert value of type 'Data' to expected argument type 'String'`.

```
func set(_ object: SwiftyJSON.JSON, for key: String) {
    guard let data = try? object.rawData() else { return }
    cache?.setObject(data, forKey: key)
}
```

other one is about `Cannot convert value of type '()?' to closure result type 'Disposable'`.

I got this error at this code.

```
self?.cache?.async.object(forKey: key) { result in
```

I can not understand how to put JSON data to cache.

I try to change the code of `.add(key, object: data)` to  `.async.setObject`.
But I can't understand how to use `setObject`.

Here is all code for cache.

```
import Foundation
import Cache
import SwiftyJSON
import RxSwift
import Async

final class CacheService {

    // MARK: - Properties
    static let shared = CacheService()

    fileprivate let cache = try? Storage(
        diskConfig: DiskConfig(name: "ReadGirl.JSONCache"),
        memoryConfig: MemoryConfig(expiry: .never, countLimit: 10, totalCostLimit: 10),
        transformer: TransformerFactory.forCodable(ofType: String.self) // Storage<User>
    )

    // MARK: - Enum Values
    enum Service: String {
        case book = "Readgirl.JSONCache.book"
        case thread = "Readgirl.JSONCache.thread"
        case sound = "Readgirl.JSONCache.sound"
    }

}

// MARK: - Save
extension CacheService {
    func set(_ object: SwiftyJSON.JSON, for service: Service) {
        set(object, for: CacheService.Service(rawValue: service.rawValue)!)
    }
    func set(_ object: SwiftyJSON.JSON, for key: String) {
        guard let data = try? object.rawData() else { return }
        cache?.setObject(data, forKey: key) <-- ERROR : Cannot convert value of type 'Data' to expected argument type 'String'
    }

}

// MARK: - Load
extension CacheService {
    func object(for service: Service) -> Observable<SwiftyJSON.JSON?> {
        return object(for: CacheService.Service(rawValue: service.rawValue)!)
    }

    func object(for key: String) -> Observable<SwiftyJSON.JSON?> {
        return Observable.create { [weak self] observer in
            //self?.cache?.async.object(forKey: key) { (data: Data?) in
            self?.cache?.async.object(forKey: key) { result in <-- ERROR : Cannot convert value of type '()?' to closure result type 'Disposable'
                switch result {
                    case .value(let data):
                        Async.userInteractive {
                            let json = SwiftyJSON.JSON(data: data)
                            Async.main {
                                if let error = json.error {
                                    observer.onError(error)
                                } else {
                                    observer.onNext(json)
                                }
                                observer.onCompleted()
                            }
                        }
                case .error(let error):
                    observer.onNext(nil)
                    observer.onCompleted()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `setObject` instead of `add(key:` as below,

```
func set(_ object: SwiftyJSON.JSON, for key: String) {
    guard let data = try? object.rawData() else { return }
    cache?.setObject(data, forKey: key)
}
```

And use `Result<Type>` to retrieve the required object from `storage` as below,

```
self?.cache?.async.object(forKey: key) { result in
  switch result {
    case .value(let data):
         Async.userInteractive {
           let json = SwiftyJSON.JSON(data: data)

            Async.main {
                if let error = json.error {
                    observer.onError(error)
                } else {
                   observer.onNext(json)
                }
                observer.onCompleted()
            }
         }
    case .error(let error):
      observer.onNext(nil)
      observer.onCompleted()
  }
}
```

Comment: Kamran, Thank you for your answer. I changed code to you teach to me.
that error was gone. but another error is coming. 

`cache?.setObject(data, forKey: key)` got the message, `Cannot convert value of type 'Data' to expected argument type 'String'`
And `self?.cache?.async.object(forKey: key) { result in` got `Cannot convert value of type '()?' to closure result type 'Disposable'`
Maybe I have to change the type.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

I edited my ask. 
you can see the code.

I think I have to convert type Data to String.
But I don't know how to covert it.